# Initializing a RecyclerView with Android Data Binding in Kotlin is throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-databinding

### Description

I am trying to set up an Android screen in Kotlin with a RecyclerView using android data binding. I have an activity that contains a fragment and the fragment contains a RecyclerView that I initialize with data binding.

The issue is that when I try to set my recycler view's layout manager the application throws an IllegalStateException complaining that the specified child (I'm assuming it means either the RecyclerView or the LayoutManager) already has a parent and that I need to run removeView(). I have tried removing all views from the RecyclerView, but to no avail.

### Here is my activity:

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            return
        }

        val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.home_fragment_container, fragment).commit()
    }
}
```

### Here is my fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentHomeBinding
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val testList = listOf("TEST TITLE")
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        mRecyclerView = mBinding.homeRecyclerview
        mRecyclerView.adapter = HomeOptionsAdapter(testList, View.OnClickListener { Log.d("[onCreateView]:", "I've been clicked") })
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        return mBinding.root
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            val fragment = HomeFragment()
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

### And here is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="joseph.kinler.mtgutility.fragments.HomeFragment">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

When I try to run this, I get an error on my recyclerview when I try to set the LayoutManager:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? Am I using data binding incorrectly? Is Kotlin just not playing well with data binding? Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

### Edit:

Here is the full stack trace for the error:

> 06-14 21:34:44.876 3631-3631/com.kinler.mtgutility E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.kinler.mtgutility, PID: 3631
>                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4885)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4716)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4656)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:751)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:7995)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7953)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:7941)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1552)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1498)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:591)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3691)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3408)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3960)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
>                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:736)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19393)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6022)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2480)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2199)
>                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1385)
>                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6722)
>                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:886)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
>                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:633)
>                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:872)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

### Edit 2:

I did a bit more debugging last night with logs and it appears that my recyclerView is initializing properly, the adapter is running, and it will create one ViewHolder and bind it before throwing an error. I am still not sure where the exact error occurs, but I am planning on adding log statements to more spots in my app flow to figure out where the problem happens.

### Edit 3:

Here is my adapter code:

```
class HomeOptionsAdapter(val items:List<String>, val itemListener: View.OnClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCardViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG = HomeOptionsAdapter::class.java.simpleName

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: HomeCardViewHolder, position: Int) = viewHolder.bind(items[position], itemListener)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeCardViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "[onCreateViewHolder]")
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = HomeCardBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return HomeCardViewHolder(binding.homeCardTitle, binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
}
```

And my View Holder code:

```
class HomeCardViewHolder constructor(itemView: View, binding: HomeCardBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val TAG = HomeCardViewHolder::class.java.simpleName
    private var mBinding: HomeCardBinding

    init {
        mBinding = binding
    }

    fun bind(title: String, listener: View.OnClickListener) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[bind]")
        mBinding.homeCardTitle.text = title
        Log.d(TAG, title)
        mBinding.homeCardTitle.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace?

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann I'm at work at the moment, but I should be able to provide it when I get home.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann in case you are still interested, I have added the full stack trace. Sorry for the late update!

Comment: Your `DataBinding` and `Kotlin` setup seems fine, i guess something might be wrong with `RecyclerView`

Comment: Post code of `recyclerViewAdapter`.

Comment: @chandil03 I have added the code for the adapter as well as the View Holder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating the view holder with `HomeCardViewHolder(binding.homeCardTitle, binding)`. The `itemView` parameter is supposed to be the root view though. Judging by the name, `homeCardTitle` might be a view in the hierarchy of the binding itself. Thus it already has a parent an cannot be added to the recycler view.

So instead instantiate the view holder with `HomeCardViewHolder(binding.root, binding)`.

Or just provide the view holder with the binding alone.

```
class HomeCardViewHolder constructor(val binding: HomeCardBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    private val TAG = HomeCardViewHolder::class.java.simpleName

    fun bind(title: String, listener: View.OnClickListener) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[bind]")
        binding.homeCardTitle.text = title
        Log.d(TAG, title)
        binding.homeCardTitle.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot that the rootView is what was required for the view holder parameter.